# sql server 2014 and xamp php 7.0

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5, php-7

I have updated four files names given below in php/ext folder of xampp
I also updated these updated lines in php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

but when I try to run `php artisan migrate` it gives me this error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>    in Unknown on line 0

what could be the possible problem?
Am I doing something wrong

I downloaded files from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: are you sure the dll file is not corrupted? did you try downloading it again maybe ?

Comment: yeah tried it twice.

Comment: now added all these again 

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll

Comment: am I missing any step?

Comment: It makes no sense mixing different platforms. Check your php. is it x64 or x86. then check if it is thread safe (ts) or non thread safe (nts). then choose a single php_sqlsrv_7xxxxx.dll and a single php_pdo_sqlsrv_7xxxx.dll depending on your php.

Comment: thanku so much, actually I thought that x64 or x86 is version of my windows. So I checked now that my php is x86 and is thread enabled so I just copied those two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I came to knew that x64 or x86 is version of php which can be obtained from phpinfo(). so my php was x86 and I was using x64 files and also my php was thread enables so I did not need nts files